# Jquery fadeIn() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

**Description:** I am trying to `fadeIn()` my container using jquery, but it doesn't work. I'm kinda new to it, only fresh out of codeacademy jquery course.

**Problem:** the method I wrote in myScript.js file doesn't seem to work. The syntax looks to be ok compared to other examples. I got my js file linked to the html file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

This is my index.cshtml file where I created a container for some navigation:

```
 <div class="container" id="fade">
        //some other buttons, divs, etc
 </div>
```

This is my custom js file that I included:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should hide the div by default if you want to fade it in, otherwise it is already showing and fading in won't do anything. If that's the case, your html should look like this:

```
<div class="container" id="fade" style="display: none;">
    //some other buttons, divs, etc
</div>
```

Comment: No reason not to upvote ZiNNED and Khalid anwsers. simple and easy to understand

Comment: Then you're either forgetting to include `jQuery`, your `myScript.js` is not correctly included, or you're doing other stuff with your `div` element (hiding its container by CSS or JS or something similar).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your **#fade** element is hidden when the page loads.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container" id="fade">
        //some other buttons, divs, etc
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fade { display: none }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
});
```